# JavaFX: unbind property without reference to property

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    TextField textField1=new TextField();
    SimpleStringProperty property=new SimpleStringProperty("Initial Value");
    textField1.textProperty().bindBidirectional(property);
    Button but1=new Button("New value");
    Button but2=new Button("Unbind");
    but1.setOnAction((event)->{
        property.set("New Value");
    });
    but2.setOnAction((event)->{
        //THIS LINE 
    });
    VBox vbox=new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(textField1,but1,but2);
    Scene scene=new Scene(vbox, 200, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

The problem is if I `THIS LINE` replace with

```
textField1.textProperty().unbind();
```

unbinding doesn't work. But if I replace with

```
textField1.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(property);
```

unbinding works.

I have a lot of properties and don't want to keep their references. Is it possible to get property from textField1 or from textField1.textProperty()? Or is it possible to unbind anyway else without reference to `property`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to do this. You can bidirectionally bind a property to any number of properties. Even if you could retrieve a list of properties to which `textField1.textProperty()` was bidirectionally bound (and I'm pretty certain there is no way to do that), how would you know which one you wanted to unbind?

"I have a lot of properties and don't want to keep their references." just suggests you need to rethink your design - you should really only be binding to things in your model, to which you would necessarily keep a reference.